# Skipping Command in CMD batch file

Tags: batch-file, windows-command-prompt

I'm using pstools to shutdown local pcs .. with different user & pass

```
psshutdown \\10.0.0.1  -u 1 -p 1
psshutdown \\10.0.0.2  -u 2 -p 2 
psshutdown \\10.0.0.3  -u 3 -p 3
```

problem is :
if one of them is down the batch take a lot of time to move to the next one ... How can i skip to the next command after some time .. or but it in a loop ... Any ideas ?

Comment: Upgrade to using Powershell, use one of the various [runspace implementations](https://github.com/RamblingCookieMonster/Invoke-Parallel) that let you mutlitask and run many commands in parallel?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [docs](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/psshutdown.aspx), you can set a timeout for connecting to the remote machine with the `-n <seconds>` option:

```
psshutdown \\10.0.0.1  -u 1 -p 1 -n 5
```